# How to get tables for distinct value of a variable that is multiple times in the data

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I didn't work with SQL much. I have a dataset with Variable A, Index, Fail and Country. Here A is unique, but we don't need that for the analysis. What I want is to find which Countries have most fail for distinct index number. So what I tried is

```
SELECT  Index, Count(Fail), Country
FROM Data
GROUP BY Country
SORT BY Count(Fail) DESC
```

But the fact is for an index we might have multiple fails, but I want count only one fail for a single index number, so for instance the Index 1 has 2 fails, 2 has 1 fail, 3 has 4 fail, I want only The count(fail) to be 3, not (2+1+4=7). FYI in the table each row represent either one fail or not. So in the table the fail values are either 0 or 1. I think, I need to include sum/distinct clause, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make a useful addition to your question, as would a *tag* for your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can put `DISTINCT`in the `COUNT()` as follows:

```
SELECT  Index, Count(DISTINCT Fail), Country
FROM Data
GROUP BY Index,Country
SORT BY Count(Fail) DESC
```

I've added `Index` in the `GROUP BY` to avoid it causing an error.

Comment: Do you mean `ORDER BY` rather than `SORT BY`?

Comment: Thank you @FlexYourData : that's how you get caught out when you correct without testing :-)

Comment: My mistake, it's sort by.